# How to get free API for vegetable and fruit rates?

Tags: json

I want API url for following categories:

Bus route schedule, vegetable rates, fruit rates, gold rates, weather reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the free API Url for weather [Open Weather](https://openweathermap.org/api)

For Gold [Gold](http://goldpricez.com/about/api)

Comment: weather report api is good